# What are the drop rate of Pyromania miscs?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What are the drop rates for the 6 items added in today's update? Is the chance to receive each item the same?

Comment: Sorry, speculation about the future are off-topic and, right as of now, no one knows what they do. Feel free to check out [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/vash9/mystery_tf2_update_for_61912/) instead. The current leading theory is the items are related to the summer sale stuff.

Comment: "Is the chance to receive each item the same?" is considered a good question for our pattern, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the drop rates between different items are almost certainly not the same.

In the last two days of idling on two accounts (two weeks' worth) I've got:

- 1 hat (woohoo!)
- 19 weapons

...and:

- 9 fish,
- 8 lint,
- 4 barn door planks,
- 3 banana peels and
- 1 cheese wheel.

This is hardly evidence but an example of what to expect. Some items are likely more rare than others.

Answer (score -2):

Most possibly Meet The Pyro items. Think about it, the burned dairy? The weapons dont have any stats and aren't even equitable. Just Valve trying to hint towards Meet The Pyro. I'm getting on to try to collect said items.

Comment: Citation needed. Speculation doesn't belong on this site :)

Comment: keep on topic of the question. Admire your interest however :).